# slide down menu in html frames

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frames

I want the slide down menu in frames in html ,when user clicks on the button which is present in top frame it should slide down how can i do that i have created the frames

```
<!-- frameset is deprecated in html5, but it still works. -->
    <frameset framespacing="0" rows="40,*,15" frameborder="1" noresize>
        <frame name="top" src="http://www.yahoo.com" target="top"></frame>
        <frame name="main" src="http://www.google.com" target="main"></frame>
        <frame name="bottom" src="http://www.facebook.com" target="bottom"></frame>
    </frameset>
```

My requirement is something like this:

> http://jsbin.com/EkAweqA/1

But i want to implement in frames

Comment: I would really advise you to not use frames, unless you're trying to make a page that looks like it was created in like 1997.

Comment: @Travesty3 i know frames are not used now a days,but my application is a legacy ,so restructuring is a bit complex

Comment: Just saw your ref link, when you click menu button top, it is getting sliding down and top of that some content are coming. is it that you want?

Comment: yes i have even implemented that also but ,its a frame so it second frame doesn't slide down

Answer (score 0):

Frames are not valid for HTML5. Now, iframes have been introduced.
You need to add a button for each iframe to show onclick. Following is the code for buttons and iframe -

```
<button id ="b1" type="button">Click Me for Yahoo!</button>
<iframe id="yahoo" src="http://www.yahoo.com"></iframe><br>

<button id ="b2" type="button">Click Me for Google!</button>
<iframe id="google" src="http://www.google.com"></iframe><br>

<button id ="b3" type="button">Click Me for Facebook!</button>
<iframe id="facebook" src="http://www.facebook.com"></iframe><br>
```

Now you need to make these iframes hide on page load as initially. Then they will appear on button click.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#yahoo").hide();
    $("#google").hide();
    $("#facebook").hide();
        $("#b1").click(function(){
            $("#yahoo").show();
        });

    $("#b2").click(function(){
            $("#google").show();
        });


    $("#b3").click(function(){
            $("#facebook").show();
        });
});
```

Comment: whole application is designed in frames so for now we can't change the frames to iframes ,is there any other solution to implement my requirement within the frames

Answer (score 0):

This code will work perfectly fine for frames also. I have checked. Just try it. 
:)